# Show that point you found for $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$ using line through$ (1, 0)$ has integer coordinates.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The curve $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$ includes the point $(1, 0)$. Let $L$ be the line through $(1, 0)$ with slope $m$. Find the other point where $L$ intersects the curve. Suppose that you take $m = v/u$, where $(u, v)$ is a solution to $u^2 - 2v^2 = 1$. Show that the point you found previously has integer coordinates.

Finding the point isn't hard but I have no idea how to go about proving that it has integer coordinates. Thank you.

Comment: which point ... ?

Comment: the one where you solve x^2 - 2y^2 =1 and y = m(x-1)

Comment: Well, what are its co-ordinates?

Comment: You have the one point $(1,0)$ and the other found by intersecting $y=m(x-1)$ with the curve, whose coordinates are certain fractional expressions involving the given slope $m.$ Then if one puts $m=u/v$ there are then still only two points so far, so it's unclear what the phrase "the point found previously" refers to.

Comment: I have found (3, 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be $y=mx+b$ where $m=v/u$ s.t. $2v^2=u^2-1$. I'll assume that $u$ and $v$ are integers with $u\neq 0$.

We're told that $0=m+b$ and so $b=-m$. The object of interest is a point $(s,t)\neq (1,0)$ s.t.
$$
t=ms-m,\quad 2t^2=s^2-1.
$$
Then $t=m(s-1)$ and
$$
s^2-1=2t^2=2m^2(s-1)^2=2(v^2/u^2)(s-1)^2=[(u^2-1)
/u^2](s-1)^2
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(s^2-1)u^2=(u^2-1)(s-1)^2\iff 0=(s-1)(2u^2-1+s).
$$
Because $s\neq 1$, we infer that $s=1-2u^2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $t=m(s-1)=-2(v/u)u^2=-2vu\in\mathbb{Z}$. You can manually verify that these $s$ and $t$ do satisfy $2t^2=s^2-1$.

---

Note that
$$
s=1-2u^2=2(1-u^2)-1=-4v^2-1<0
$$
whereas the sign of $t$ is arbitrary because $2v^2=u^2-1$ doesn't pin down the signs of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you reched from (s^2−1)u^2=(u^2−1)(s−1)^2 to 0=(s−1)(2u^2−1+s). Apart from that think I understood the idea :)

Comment: @Andrew Just factor LHS - RHS. You notice that $(s^2-1)=(s-1)(s+1)$ so extracting the $(s-1)$ factor is immediate.

Comment: Just one last thing, is there a way to check that a solution I get is in positive integers? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Andrew I added a bit concerning the signs.

Answer (score 0):

We have

[image]

Then the ligne y = m(x – 1) cuts the hyperbole besides of the point (1, 0) at point x root of the equation $x^2$ + 2($u^2$ - 1)x – (2$u^2$ - 1) = 0. Then x = -2$u^2$ - 1, an integer.

WARNING: I have stopped at x = -2$u^2$ - 1 trusting about the other coordinate. However it is equal to
[image]

and the question faces an obstacle. It is probably false unless the only possibility be (u, v) = (2, 3) in order to have the exposed condition of (u, v) be a point of the hiperbola.This is a diophantine equation to be solved.

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Andrew:  Explain please what do you mean by "I have found (3, 2)" in your comment. In the figure you have in red the corresponding straight line which is not very satisfactory. I believed in the statement of your question but I am confused now about it.

[image]